# Extract text from between parentheses

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to extract text from between parentheses and ideally get a list of strings with the contents of the parentheses. Example

```
"ab(cde)fgh(ij)k" -> ["cde", "ij"]
```

```
combine :: [a] -> [a] ->[[a]]
combine x y = [x, y]

extract x =
  combine y (extract (drop (length z) x))
  where z = takeWhile (/= ')') x
        y = dropWhile (/= '(') z
```

I get this error:

```
Couldn't match type '[Char]' with `Char'
    Expected type: [Char] -> [Char]
      Actual type: [Char] -> [[Char]]
```

Comment: And what goes wrong? From a first read, I'm guessing the compiler gives you a type error. If so, what parts of the error do you understand? What parts do you find confusing?

Comment: @DanielWagner It is a type error. One of the functions expects a string but gets a char or the other way around. I have no idea which one it is.

Comment: Here's a hint: when you get an error you don't understand, it usually helps to post the text of that error in your question, so that people answering it can see what went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues in your code but I hope I understood the idea of it.

First your `combine` - if you look how you use it: It should return what your `extract` returns (from your example a *list of `String`*) and the second parameter is the same type (as it's the result from a recursive `extract`) - so it needs to have type (or a type you can unify with) `String -> [String] -> [String]` - looking at what it's supposed to do this is really just the *cons* of a list (the `:` operator).

Next you mixed `x,y,z` in a way I think you didn't really want to - you combine with `y` but `y` seems to be the part *to* the first `(` you find - but you want to collect the parts inside `(..)` - similar with how you define and use `z`.

Finally fixing that your code would work but you would collect `(` too.

This one is a version fixing that stuff for you:

```hs
extract :: String -> [String]
extract txt 
  | null begin = []
  | otherwise = part : extract rest
  where 
    begin = dropWhile (/= '(') txt
    after = tail begin
    part = takeWhile (/= ')') after
    rest = drop (length part + 1) after
```

**note** that there is still an issue (try `"ab(cde)fgh(ij)k(hmmmm"` and see what happens) - I'm sure you can fix that yourself now.